# Matrix Inversions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem:

"Suppose $P$ is invertible and $A=PBP^{-1}$. Solve for $B$ in terms of $A$."

As far as I can tell, the value of $B$ depends of the values of both $A$ and $P$, not just $A$. My solution is this:

$A=PBP^{-1}$

$AP=PBI=PB$

$P^{-1}AP=IB=B$

$B=P^{-1}AP$

Is this correct, or is there a way to solve for $B$ in terms of $A$ only? This is a homework question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes. I think it's correct.

Comment: Thank you. Am I wrong to assume that when a question asks for an answer in terms of A then that answer should not include other variables? That was how I was taught. So, I would say that this answer is "B in terms of A and P."

Comment: $P$ isn't a variable, $P$ is a matrix that depends entirely on $A$. It's essentially a constant, although we might not know what it is. It's like saying "solve $\frac{y}{x} = 5$ for $y$ in terms of $x$; you don't need to declare $5$ as something special. Either way, that's mere pedantry.

Comment: Yes; in this situation, it seems clear you are wrong to assume that.  Terminology may vary between authors, though.

Comment: Ok. Thank you clarifying.